# How to connect another database in maven project at the time of login, after building the war with one database?

Tags: java, mysql, maven

Initially the war was build with production database. In the login web service, we have one parameter to specify the application to connect the production db or training db. If the user gives the production db as the parameter, then there is no problem. Else if user gives training db as the parameter, then how to connect and get/update in the training db.
Is it possible to do in the maven project?

Please help to solve this issue.

Comment: Need more information like how you are connecting to the database (by code or connection pooling)? Are you using any framework?

Comment: <bean id="dataSource"
  class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    
  <property name="driverClassName" value="${database.className}" />
  <property name="url" value="${database.url}" />
  <property name="username" value="${database.username}" />
  <property name="password" value="${database.password}" />  
 </bean> The exact values will come from properties file.

Comment: So you are using Spring then use spring profile.

Comment: Its not clear. Please let me know if you need any information

Comment: Ref: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#beans-definition-profiles-xml

Comment: Thanks. I will check and let you know.

Comment: Hi, <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource"> <property name="driverClassName" value="${database.className}" /> <property name="url" value="${database.url}" /> <property name="username" value="${database.username}" /> <property name="password" value="${database.password}" /> </bean>. I want to change the url in the property tag and connect the new database. After connecting, the application should get and update from and to the new database. Is it possible to do? Please help me to resolve this issue.